# Why does localhost:5000 not work in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I'm using flask app factory pattern like and have this run.py file:

```
from app import create_app

app = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='localhost', debug=True)
```

Then I run the app like this:

```
python run.py
```

But when I go to http://localhost:5000 it doesn't work.
It says:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL
>   manually please check your spelling and try again.

What could be wrong? it works well when I have 127.0.0.1 address...

I need to run on "localhost" because I'm integrating square payments and their sandbox setup requires I make requests to their API from a 'localhost'.

Also, when I make the request in the browser, on the terminal when flask responds there is this:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Sep/2017 00:30:45] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Sep/2017 00:30:45] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Sep/2017 00:30:45] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

So it looks like request reaches flask but flask returns 404.

Here is part of my **init**.py file:

```
# from __future__ import print_function


# import flask
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, redirect, flash, request, \
    session, current_app, abort
import os
# flask sqlaclhemy
from sqlalchemy import func, desc, asc, or_, and_

from flask_admin import Admin, AdminIndexView
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView

# Flask secrutiy
from flask_security import (Security, SQLAlchemyUserDatastore, 
    login_required, current_user)
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_mail import Mail

# square connect setup
import uuid
import squareconnect
from squareconnect.rest import ApiException
# from squareconnect.apis.locations_api import LocationsApi
from squareconnect.apis.transactions_api import TransactionsApi




mail = Mail()

class CustomAdminIndexView(AdminIndexView):
    def is_accessible(self):
        return current_user.is_authenticated and current_user.has_role('admin')

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(os.environ['APP_SETTINGS'])
    mail.init_app(app)
    from models import db, User, Role
    db.init_app(app)

    user_datastore = SQLAlchemyUserDatastore(db, User, Role)
    security = Security(app, user_datastore)

    @app.route('/')
    def home():
        return render_template('home.html')

    return app
```

Comment: Are you using linux?

Comment: have you tried passing an explicit port when calling app.run(host='localhost', port=5000) ?

Comment: Does localhost resolve to 127.0.0.1 for you?  (e.g. by a hosts file entry)

Comment: cat /etc/hosts. Is there an entry with 127.0.0.1 and localhost on the same line? If not, add it.

Comment: Yes, there is a line: 127.0.0.1    localhost in the hosts file

Comment: You have not configured any route, so it works as it should. Any network-layer concerns are not relevant.

Answer (score 23):

Just incase anyone on a mac runs into this issue and has trouble finding any answers (like me), I just discovered that it's because Apple Airplay Receiver runs on port 5000.  Disable airplay receiver and try again.

Comment: this actually was exactly the answer I was looking for. Thx

Answer (score 10):

The simple alternative solution is first to check if port 5000 is available; you can check that with this command:

```
netstat -lat
```

find more about available ports [here](https://superuser.com/a/885440) :
if you are not obliged to use port 5000 you can try anything else you want ..
if everything is ok, that means you have a problem with your home page; you don't have a route to '/' , and that is why you are getting the 404 error when you go to localhost:5000/ :
So to correct it, you have 3 solutions:

1. add the app.route('/') in your **init**.py  file
2. add it directly in your run.py after creating the app (not a good way)
3. try to use blueprints

as you didn't provide your **init**.py code let's add it to your run.py,

```
from app import create_app
app = create_app()
@app.route('/')
def homepage():
    return 'hello world'
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='localhost', port=9874)
```

another solution, as suggested in the comment, is to check if 127.0.0.1 resolves to localhost; find the host file by typing this command and check if you have the same line as mine :

```
nano /etc/hosts
```

and open the file :

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

Comment: I do have a line for localhost in hosts file. Also tried it with a different port. Still doesn't work.

Comment: I can see the flask server receiving the get request, but still everything returns 404 from flask.

Comment: If tou see the flask server that mean your server is running, tell me do you have a route to home?? show me your view function.  Let me edit the answer

Comment: Hi, I edited the question and included part of my __init__.py file. I also tried just adding it to the run.py file  and still doesn't go throught. It shows up in the flask server log but says 404 not found :(

Comment: Yes, if I run it on 127.0.0.1 it works, it shows my home. Html but if I change it to "localhost", it reaches flask but flask returns 404.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use only 'localhost' in your api?? Andy orher domain name like : "myapp.com" can works ?? If yes let me know i have a suggestion .

Comment: Yes, I have to use "localhost" it's a requirement by square payments. Or else the API won't work unless it's live but I gotta test first because it's payment processing.

Comment: Have you tried binding to all IPs instead of a hostname? `app.run('0.0.0.0')`

Comment: I don't think that will help me because I need to be able to go to localhost in my browser, actually type in localhost instead of 0.0.0.0.

Comment: It will help you. Try it.

Comment: Give us an ideas about your etc/hosts file

Comment: Ok, I figured it out, I had this in my config.py: SERVER_NAME = 'localhost', i removed that line and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

there will be no entry as **localhost** in your hosts file

## example host file

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

you can check  your hosts file in following ways

## for linux

```
sudo vi /etc/hosts
```

## for windows

```
open this file C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts
```

if there is no localhost in your hosts file add and save it.

Comment: On Windows, if Docker Desktop is installed the mapping is overwritten by it. I changed the mapping back to localhost and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You should try switching out `localhost` for `0.0.0.0`.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

This has it serve on localhost for me.

Answer (score 1):

For Mac users like me who spent way too much time reading through answers to find the solution: In 2004 Apple started using port 5000 and starting with MacOS Monterey the Airplay occupied port 5000 and the default state was changed to ON. This means you can't use airplay and dev on that port simultaneously.  Someone mentioned this above, but I wanted to show the exact toggle to turn this off in a screenshot in 2024 for OS Sonoma.

Apple forum link: https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/682332

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
```

@app.route("/")
def hello():
return "Hello"
if **name** == "**main**":
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=9874)

Comment: from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def hello():
     return "Hello"
if __name__ == "__main__":
     app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=9874)

Comment: mention (host ='localhost' port = 5000)

Comment: or else  port = 9874

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

everything is working fine for me when I give port 5000 to the localhost as you can see here [image]

Answer (score -1):

May be you need to install virtual enviroment

> pip install virtualenv

does this. Hope this works

Comment: This is good practice when creating flask projects.  I would add that a virtual environment needs to be created as well using $virtualenv ['filename'], not sure if this fixes the localhost issue though